# Checkbox to button focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple forms on my page. In one form I've got 3 text fields a check box and a button. When the tab key is pressed, it goes to the 3 text fields and then to the checkbox and then no where.

How can I focus the button (`submit`) after the checkbox (`maths`) and then back to the first text field (`user_id`).

```
<form id="form13">
User ID :<input type="text" id="user_id" /><br>
Password:  <input type="password" id="password" /><br>
Department:  <input type="text" id="department" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="maths" value="on"> Maths
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

     $('#maths').keydown(function(e){
        if (e.which  == 9){
            $('#submit).focus();
        }
      });
```

Comment: So, you wants to actually handle tabbing ?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `tabindex` to the order in which you want the fields and then the button to focus? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: @hmd Thank you. yes.

Answer (score 2):

If your need is to handle Tabbing in your HTML forms. Then you may need to handle this with [HTML attribute `tabindex` this is a good article for learning purpose](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutors/forms/article.php/3479201):

```
<input id="foo" tabindex="1"  />
<input id="bar" tabindex="3"  />
<input id="awesome" tabindex="2"  />
```

So, you can handle it in your way. And yes, you can also change it dynamically by using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("foo").tabIndex = "3";
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to sent tabindex in each form?

Comment: It depends on your requirement, if you wants to set indexing in each form you can do this. There is also another type of `tabindex` by usage its called `Global Tabindex` it will give you ability to set your Tab index in all over the web page [this is a good article on tabindex for learning purpose](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutors/forms/article.php/3479201) .

Answer (score 0):

You should organize your form in such a way that it can be navigated using the keyboard only.
For example, have a look at this form:
[Accessible Signup form](https://rawgit.com/ravishtiwari/html-site/master/src/partials/form.html)

Manually setting the tabindex may lead to problematic behavior. There are couple of good article why you should not do it:

- [Using the tabindex attribute](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/)
- [Don’t Use Tabindex Greater than 0](http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html)

Be aware when manually setting a tabindex as suggested, this will affect natural flow of tab index in form and document. Use this only when you are absolutely sure about it.

You can organize your form in such a way that keyboard navigation of your form works without you using tabindex.

Have a look at following Pen : [Form field focus](http://codepen.io/ravishtiwari/pen/BKPjXw), you'll see that from checkbox, the focus goes directly to submit button and back :

```
<form id="form13">
  <label for="asdfg-user_id" id="user_id-ariaLabel">
User ID: <input type="text" id="asdfg-user_id" />
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="password" id="password-ariaLabel">
Password:  <input type="password" id="password" />
  </label>
  <br>
<label for="password" id="password-ariaLabel">  
Department:  <input type="text" id="department" />
  </label> 
  <br>
  <fieldset id="interestInfo">
        <legend>Subject </legend>
        <div>
            <div id="interests"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input id="chk_Subject_1_lbl" name="chk_Subject[]"
                           type="checkbox"
                           value="on"/>
                    <span>
                        <label for="chk_Subject_1" id="AreaOfInterest_1-ariaLabel" >Math</label>
                    </span>
                </div>
              <div class="row">
                    <input id="chk_Subject_2_lbl" name="chk_Subject[]"
                           type="checkbox"
                           value="on"/>
                    <span>
                        <label for="chk_Subject_2" id="AreaOfInterest_2-ariaLabel" >Chemistry</label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```